# AngularJS intellisense Visual Studio 2015 HTML pages - NO resharper

Tags: angularjs, visual-studio-2015

I am using Visual Studio community 2015, and I want to have intellisense for Angular JS. I have added angular through nuget manager, and it's referenced in my HTML page. When I would like to type a name for a directive like: ng-app, or anything, it doesn't show intellisense. I've seen some solutions on Stackoverflow, but they are related to using resharper.

Note I also don't have intellisense in my JS files as well.

Comment: intellisense for JS is provided through TypeScript in VS2015.  If you don't have TypeScript installed, you won't get intellisense support for any JS, including angular.

Comment: @Claies thanks for your answer. It's been like 30 mins since Typescript started downloading and it's installed and I don't see the intellisense working. Can you clarify more on what's needed to be done? Thank you.

Comment: it's working in the HTML page, but not in .js files..

Comment: `Tools -> options` then `Text Editor -> JavaScript -> IntelliSense`, check that `Show syntax errors` is checked under Validation.  Also check in the next level down `References`, `Implicit (Web)` Reference Group, ensure you have valid references for domWeb.js, Modern.Intellisense.js, etc.

Comment: I have show syntax checked. Though in the References section, I have only these: libhelp.js, sitetypesWeb.js, domWeb.js, underscorefilter.js and showPlainComments.js, there's no Modern.Intellisense.js. I added references file manually to my project and added references to the angular.js file, it didn't work. It works only if I add `/// <reference ` to each .js file. Any idea?

Comment: I just looked it up, `Modern.Intellisense.js` comes from [Web Essentials 2015](http://vswebessentials.com/download#WE2015), and adds support for quite a few apis.  Web Essentials can also automatically create `/// <reference` files for you.  You shouldn't need to add reference paths in every javascript file, though....

Comment: the official document on the subject might have some help too https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb385682.aspx